# async Task if condition fails again coming to if condition

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a **async Task** method. The below method is executing and no issues. But when condition fails in try block I am just using *return* is it a good way I'm not sure and I am returning the error code and message and the if condition is **hit two times** in the try block  .I doubt this might not work for 10 concurrent users.Please correct me the code changes to be done.

```
public class VSphereDelegatingHandler
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public VSphereDelegatingHandler(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                int a = 1;
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    context.Response.Clear();
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("This is invalid");
                    return;
                }
                await _next.Invoke(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("Header information for ApiKey is missin")
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What the code is doing is very different than your description of what the code is doing. Could you 1) provide a simple example, 2) describe what the expected behavior is, and 3) ask a question.

Comment: RequestDelegate is a concept where the request and response api  is being handled by that class. In that class we are using Task async method to invoke next api call.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1